# Show that $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{\alpha ^2}{\alpha ^2 +\lambda ^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\alpha }$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Fix that $\alpha >0$ and consider the function $f(x)=e^{-2\pi \alpha |x|} $,$x\in \mathbb{R}$
1.Compute the fourier transform of $f$.
2.Show that $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{\alpha ^2}{\alpha ^2 +w ^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\alpha }$

We have that $\hat{f}(w)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)e^{-2\pi iwx}dx$ and i find that $\hat{f}(w)= \frac {\alpha}{\pi(\alpha ^2 + w^2)}.$
For the second question we have that $$\hat{f}(w)= \frac {\alpha}{\pi(\alpha ^2 + w^2)}$$ then  $$\hat{\hat{f}}(w)= F(\frac {\alpha}{\pi(\alpha ^2 + w^2)})$$ by the inverse theorem we have $$\hat{\hat{f}}(w)=f(-x)$$
and $$F(\frac {\alpha}{\pi(\alpha ^2 + w^2)})=\alpha \pi F(\frac{\alpha ^2}{\alpha ^2 + w^2}) $$
we finally we got $$e^{-2\pi \alpha |x|}=\alpha \pi \int_{\mathbb R}  \frac{\alpha ^2}{\alpha ^2 +w ^2}e^{-2\pi iwx}dx$$ we take $x=0$ we got  $$ \int_{\mathbb R}  \frac{\alpha ^2}{\alpha ^2 +w ^2}= \frac{1}{\alpha \pi }$$
I got wrong result.
Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: The step $F(\frac {\alpha}{\pi(\alpha ^2 + w^2)})=\alpha \pi F(\frac{1}{\alpha ^2 + w^2}) $ is wrong. The multiplicative factor should be $\alpha/\pi$.

Comment: The result you're being asked to prove is wrong in the first place. Plug in $\alpha=1$ and you'll see why.

Comment: @cjferes sorry edited  $\alpha ^2$ not $1$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I put $1$ instead of $\alpha ^2$

Comment: For $\alpha=1$ the integral should be $\pi$, but in your formula you need to prove it is $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Andrei so am i wrong on the first question ?

Comment: No, you got the first question right. The second result you are trying to prove is wrong. The correct result is
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+w^2}dw=\alpha \pi\neq \frac{\pi}{2\alpha}$$
You can get this after noting that $F(\frac {\alpha}{\pi(\alpha ^2 + w^2)})=\alpha \pi F(\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha ^2 + w^2})$ should actually be $F(\frac {\alpha}{\pi(\alpha ^2 + w^2)})=\frac{1}{\alpha \pi} F(\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha ^2 + w^2})$.

Comment: @projectilemotion Yes you're right  i mistyping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another quick way, due to the definition of Fourier transform, is
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+w^2}\mathrm{d}w = \left.\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+w^2}e^{iwx}\mathrm{d}w\right|_{x=0} = \pi\alpha\,\mathscr{F}^{-1}\left[\frac{\alpha}{\pi(\alpha^2+w^2)}\right](0) = \left.\pi\alpha e^{-2\pi\alpha|x|}\right|_{x=0} = \pi\alpha
$$

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution to $(2)$ is the following. By the change of variable $w = \alpha x$,
$$
\int_{\Bbb R} \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+w^2} \,\mathrm d w = \int_{\Bbb R} \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2} \,\alpha\,\mathrm d x = \alpha \int_{\Bbb R} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm d x
\\
= \alpha \,\Big[\arctan\Big]_{-\infty}^\infty = \alpha\,\pi.
$$